# Module 'pygame' has no 'KEYDOWN' member

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to PyGame and just trying to mak it detect pressed keys bbut the error 
"Module 'pygame' has no 'KEYDOWN' member" Appears.
I've tried alot of other suggestions for others problems but none have worked for me

```
import pygame as Game
import sys, time
from random import randrange

# Setup Variables
Width = 500
Height = 500
Change_To = Direction

# Initialize PyGame
Check_Errors = Game.init()
# Check for errors in initializing PyGame
if Check_Errors[1] != 0:
    print("(!)There were {0} initializing errors, 
EXITING...".format(Check_Errors[1]))
    sys.exit
else:
    print("PyGame initialized successfully!")

# Setup Game Board
Board = Game.display.set_mode([Width, Height])
Game.display.set_caption("Snake Game!")

# Setup Events
while True:
    for Event in Game.event.get():
        if Event.type == Game.KEYDOWN:
            if Event.key == Game.K_UP:
                Change_To = 'UP'
            if Event.key == Game.K_LEFT:
                Change_To = 'LEFT'
            if Event.key == Game.K_DOWN:
                Change_To = 'DOWN'
            if Event.key == Game.K_RIGHT:
                Change_To = 'RIGHT'
```

Comment: It looks like your pygame installation might be broken, try reinstalling it. I've no clue as to why this is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted works when I try it, and it reports KEYDOWN events as expected.

Is your Python module called `Game`?

And by the way, `sys.exit` in your initialization error check doesn't do what you think it does. It should be `sys.exit()`.